# How do you do a "staircase align" in Latex?

Tags: math-mode, align, alignat

I want to create something like

[image]

or

[image]

where the = is aligned with the last character of the previous equation. But I'm not sure how to make this work.

I've tried,

```
\begin{align} a = b & \\ 
                    & = c & \\
                          & = d  \end{align}
```

But this doesn't give me what I want

Comment: Since @StevenB.Segletes's very nice [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/590739) doesn't seem explicitly to mention it, note that the reason your solution doesn't work is that, despite the suggestive spacing, the `&` at the beginning of the `= d` line has no idea it's meant to match up with the *second* `&` on the previous line.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
a = b & &&\\ 
                  & {}= c &&\\
                  &     &{} = d &\\
                  &     &      &{} = e 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You could use an `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{array}{*5{l@{\;}}}
    a = & b \\
        & = & c \\
        &   & = & d \\
        &   &   & = & e
\end{array} \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `alignat`, but it's handier if we don't have to compute the number of necessary `&`'s and let TeX do it.

The main left-hand side is given as argument to the environment, the rest is in the environment, lines separated by `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{staircase}{mb}
 {
  \procyonic_staircase:nnn { } { #1 } { #2 }
 }
 {}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{staircase*}{mb}
 {
  \procyonic_staircase:nnn { * } { #1 } { #2 }
 }
 {}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \procyonic_staircase:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__procyonic_staircase_seq { \\ } { #3 }
  \begin{alignat#1}{ \int_eval:n { \seq_count:N \l__procyonic_staircase_seq + 1 } }
  #2 ={} &
  \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l__procyonic_staircase_seq \__procyonic_staircase:nn 
  \end{alignat#1}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__procyonic_staircase_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__procyonic_staircase:nn
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1*2 } { & }
  \int_compare:nF { #1 = 1 } { \negthickspace = }
  #2
  \int_compare:nF { #1 = \seq_count:N \l__procyonic_staircase_seq } { \\ }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{staircase}{a}
 b \\ c \\ d
\end{staircase}

\begin{staircase*}{a}
 b \\ c \\ d
\end{staircase*}

\end{document}
```

[image]